# How to implement sql coalesce in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,np.nan],"B":[np.nan,10,np.nan], "C":[5,10,7]})
     A     B   C
0  1.0   NaN   5
1  2.0  10.0  10
2  NaN   NaN   7
```

I want to add a new column 'D'. Expected output is

```
     A     B   C    D
0  1.0   NaN   5    1.0
1  2.0  10.0  10    2.0
2  NaN   NaN   7    7.0
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The value of `df` in your first code snippet is wrong. And how do you calculate the expected output?

Answer (score 23):

Another way is to explicitly fill column D with A,B,C in that order.

```
df['D'] = np.nan
df['D'] = df.D.fillna(df.A).fillna(df.B).fillna(df.C)
```

Answer (score 13):

Another approach is to use the `combine_first` method of a `pd.Series`.  Using your example `df`,

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,np.nan],"B":[np.nan,10,np.nan], "C":[5,10,7]})
>>> df
     A     B   C
0  1.0   NaN   5
1  2.0  10.0  10
2  NaN   NaN   7
```

we have

```py
>>> df.A.combine_first(df.B).combine_first(df.C)
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    7.0
```

We can use `reduce` to abstract this pattern to work with an arbitrary number of columns.

```py
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> cols = [df[c] for c in df.columns]
>>> reduce(lambda acc, col: acc.combine_first(col), cols)
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    7.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Let's put this all together in a function.

```py
>>> def coalesce(*args):
...     return reduce(lambda acc, col: acc.combine_first(col), args)
...
>>> coalesce(*cols)
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    7.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 10):

I think you need [`bfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.bfill.html) with selecting first column by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
df['D'] = df.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:,0]
print (df)
     A     B   C    D
0  1.0   NaN   5  1.0
1  2.0  10.0  10  2.0
2  NaN   NaN   7  7.0
```

same as:

```
df['D'] = df.fillna(method='bfill',axis=1).iloc[:,0]
print (df)
     A     B   C    D
0  1.0   NaN   5  1.0
1  2.0  10.0  10  2.0
2  NaN   NaN   7  7.0
```

Comment: Quite inefficient as it creates a DataFrame with the same number of columns as the original and then just uses one of them.

Answer (score 7):

***option 1***
***`pandas`***

```
df.assign(D=df.lookup(df.index, df.isnull().idxmin(1)))

     A     B   C    D
0  1.0   NaN   5  1.0
1  2.0  10.0  10  2.0
2  NaN   NaN   7  7.0
```

***option 2***
***`numpy`***

```
v = df.values
j = np.isnan(v).argmin(1)
df.assign(D=v[np.arange(len(v)), j])

     A     B   C    D
0  1.0   NaN   5  1.0
1  2.0  10.0  10  2.0
2  NaN   NaN   7  7.0
```

---

***naive time test***
*over given data*

[image]

*over larger data*

[image]

Comment: If I only want 'A' and 'C' for creating 'D', then where can I specify it. Please let me know

Comment: @Anoop you can run these approaches on `df[['A', 'C']]`.  This works particularly well for the `numpy` approach.  `v = df[['A', 'C']].values`

Answer (score 0):

There is already a method for Series in Pandas that does this:

```
df['D'] = df['A'].combine_first(df['C'])
```

Or just stack them if you want to look up values sequentially:

```
df['D'] = df['A'].combine_first(df['B']).combine_first(df['C'])
```

This outputs the following:

```py
>>> df
     A     B   C    D
0  1.0   NaN   5  1.0
1  2.0  10.0  10  2.0
2  NaN   NaN   7  7.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple function that generalises the `fillna` solution:

```
def coalesce(df, order):
    result = df[order[0]]
    for column in order[1:]:
        result = result.fillna(df[column])
    return result

df["D"] = coalesce(df, ["A", "B", "C"])
```