# merging column values of same df in Pandas df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 columns in my pandas dataframe which will have some empty rows as well as non-empty rows. I have to make a 4th column combining all the 3 columns.

For example:

`df`

```
col1 col2 col3
a    NA   NA
b    NA   NA
c    NA   NA
NA   d    NA
NA   e    NA
NA   NA   f
NA   NA   g
NA   NA   h
```

Expected Output:

`df`

```
col1 col2 col3 col4
a    NA    NA   a
b    NA    NA   b
c    NA    NA   c
NA   d     NA   d
NA   e     NA   e
NA   NA    f    f
NA   NA    g    g
NA   NA    h    h
```

Comment: do you always have a single non-NA per row?

Answer (score 0):

You can fill the values per row and get the first/last column:

```
df['col4'] = df.bfill(axis=1).iloc[:,0]
```

or

```
df['col4'] = df.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:,-1]
```

Alternatively, if there is really only **one** value per row, you can use `stack`:

```
df['col4'] = df.stack().droplevel(1)
```

output:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4
0    a  NaN  NaN    a
1    b  NaN  NaN    b
2    c  NaN  NaN    c
3  NaN    d  NaN    d
4  NaN    e  NaN    e
5  NaN  NaN    f    f
6  NaN  NaN    g    g
7  NaN  NaN    h    h
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43177685/how-to-implement-sql-coalesce-in-pandas

Comment: I missed, because no comment for me. I going convert to wiki, can you convert too?

Comment: Can you give me dupe link, if close like dupe question with my answet? Because sometimes not notice it.