# Merge three columns into one taking into account priority preference

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame in pandas:

| code | town | village | city |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Brunete | NaN | NaN |
| 02 | NaN | Cabrera d'Anoia | NaN |
| 03 | NaN | NaN | Barcelona |
| 04 | Zarzalejo | NaN | Madrid |
| 07 | Melilla | NaN | City of Melilla |
| 08 | Cartagena | Galifa | Region of Murcia |

I want to merge the columns `town`, `city` and `village` into one. In case more than 1 column contains a value other than NaN, the resulting column will be assigned the value in this order of preference: `village` > `town` > `city`. Example:

| code | merged_column |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | Brunete |
| 02 | Cabrera d'Anoia |
| 03 | Barcelona |
| 04 | Zarzalejo |
| 07 | Melilla |
| 08 | Galifa |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us define the `order` of columns then select those columns and use `backfill` along columns axis

```
order = ['village', 'town', 'city']
df['merged'] = df[order].bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]
```

---

```
   code       town          village              city           merged
0     1    Brunete              NaN               NaN          Brunete
1     2        NaN  Cabrera d'Anoia               NaN  Cabrera d'Anoia
2     3        NaN              NaN         Barcelona        Barcelona
3     4  Zarzalejo              NaN            Madrid        Zarzalejo
4     7    Melilla              NaN           Melilla          Melilla
5     8  Cartagena           Galifa  Region of Murcia           Galifa
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a `coalesce` pandas version. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43177685/how-to-implement-sql-coalesce-in-pandas) you can find a related question to this.

An alternative method is the [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) method, which can be translated to the `sql-coalesce` function:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"code": ["01", "02", "03", "04", "07", "08"],
    "town": ["Brunete", pd.NA, pd.NA, "Zarzalejo", "Melilla", "Cartagena"],
    "village": [pd.NA, "Cabrera d'Anoia", pd.NA, pd.NA, pd.NA, "Galifa"],
    "city": [pd.NA, pd.NA, "Barcelona", "Madrid", "Melilla", "Region of Murcia"]}
)

df["village"].combine_first(df["town"]).combine_first(df["city"])

----------------------------
0            Brunete
1    Cabrera d'Anoia
2          Barcelona
3          Zarzalejo
4            Melilla
5             Galifa
Name: village, dtype: object
-----------------------------
```